Ошибка в import | Discord.py
Ошибка:

(venv) PS C:\Users\urijs\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\server> python mine.py
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\urijs\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\server\mine.py", line 3, in

from discord_slash import Option ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord_slash'

Но pip list:

discord.py               2.3.2
discord-py-interactions  4.4.1
discord-py-slash-command 4.2.1

Пробовал:
Заменить на pip install discord-py-interactions
Через GitHub: pip install git+https://github.com/eunwoo1104/discord-py-slash-command.git
Переустанавливал discord-slash-commands
Менял версию Python
Появилась проблема после переустановки discord.py

библиотека discord.py уже давно не поддерживается и могут возникать ошибки на стороне этой библиотеки, лучше используй модуль disnake он очень похож по структуре на discord.py так что переучиваться не придется

Мне было легче просто прейти на чуть более старую версию Python, но спасибо.

Могу посоветовать использовать py-cord. Среди всех самое лучшее решение, как по мне.

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
